# How to populate a dropdown from a JSON file based on user selection of 1st dropdown and filter duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic, dropdown

I have a JSON data file with 4 variables: ID, tumor type, treatment regimen and dose.

Using this data I want to create 3 drop down lists where the user can select the tumor type, regimen and dose populated from the json file.

The same tumor type and regimen appears multiple times so the drop down lists need to be filtered to only display unique items.

Finally the regimen and dose dropdown lists need to be dynamically updated based on what the user selected in the 1st (tumor_type) dropdown. e.g. if tumor_type CRC is selected then only regimens applicable to CRC should appear.

So far I have only managed to populate the first dropdown tumor_type with unique values.

Any help gratefully received. Thanks

Jsfiddle also here: https://jsfiddle.net/rgqxn0t4/2/

```
<select id="tumor_type"  onchange=tumor_type_change()>
<option value="0">SELECT tumor type</option></select>
<select id="regimen"  onchange=regimen_change()>
<option value="0">SELECT regimen</option></select>
<select id="dose"  onchange=dose_change()>
                      <option value="0">SELECT dose</option></select>


const data= [
  {
  "ID": "1", 
    "Tumor_type": "crc",
    "Regimen": "CAPOX",
    "Dose": "high"
  },
  {
  "ID": "2", 
    "Tumor_type": "crc",
    "Regimen": "CAPOX",
    "Dose": "low"
  },
  {
        "ID": "3",  
    "Tumor_type": "crc",
    "Regimen": "FOLFOX",
    "Dose": "high"
  },
  {
    "ID": "4", 
    "Tumor_type": "crc",
    "Regimen": "FOLFOX",
    "Dose": "low"
  },
  {
    "ID": "5", 
    "Tumor_type": "Gastric",
    "Regimen": "FOLFOX",
    "Dose": "high"
  },
  {
    "ID": "6", 
    "Tumor_type": "Gastric",
    "Regimen": "FOLFOX",
    "Dose": "low"
  },
    {
    "ID": "7", 
    "Tumor_type": "Gastric",
    "Regimen": "FOLFIRI",
    "Dose": "high"
  },
  {
    "ID": "8", 
    "Tumor_type": "Gastric",
    "Regimen": "FOLFIRI",
    "Dose": "low"
  }
  ]
  
  let dropdown1 = document.getElementById('tumor_type');
  dropdown1.length = 0;

  let defaultOption1 = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption1.text = 'Select tumor type';

dropdown1.add(defaultOption1);
dropdown1.selectedIndex = 0;


  let dropdown2 = document.getElementById('regimen');


  let dropdown3 = document.getElementById('dose');
  

        let option1;

        let data1 = Array.from(new Set(data.map(({ Tumor_type }) => Tumor_type))); 
        
        for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
          option1 = document.createElement('option');
          option1.text = data1[i];
          option1.value = data1[i].i;
          dropdown1.add(option1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the regimen and dose selects, you can `filter` based on the type first before mapping and creating a `Set`.

```js
const data=[{ID:"1",Tumor_type:"crc",Regimen:"CAPOX",Dose:"high"},{ID:"2",Tumor_type:"crc",Regimen:"CAPOX",Dose:"low"},{ID:"3",Tumor_type:"crc",Regimen:"FOLFOX",Dose:"high"},{ID:"4",Tumor_type:"crc",Regimen:"FOLFOX",Dose:"low"},{ID:"5",Tumor_type:"Gastric",Regimen:"FOLFOX",Dose:"high"},{ID:"6",Tumor_type:"Gastric",Regimen:"FOLFOX",Dose:"low"},{ID:"7",Tumor_type:"Gastric",Regimen:"FOLFIRI",Dose:"high"},{ID:"8",Tumor_type:"Gastric",Regimen:"FOLFIRI",Dose:"low"}];
const dropdown1 = document.getElementById('tumor_type');
const dropdown2 = document.getElementById('regimen');
const dropdown3 = document.getElementById('dose');
for (const t of new Set(data.map(x => x.Tumor_type)))
    dropdown1.add(new Option(t));
dropdown1.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const type = dropdown1.value;
    dropdown2.replaceChildren();
    for (const r of new Set(data.filter(x => x.Tumor_type === type).map(x => x.Regimen)))
        dropdown2.add(new Option(r));
    dropdown3.replaceChildren();
    for (const d of new Set(data.filter(x => x.Tumor_type === type).map(x => x.Dose)))
        dropdown3.add(new Option(d));
});
```

```html
<select id="tumor_type">
  <option value="0">SELECT tumor type</option>
</select>
<select id="regimen">
  <option value="0">SELECT regimen</option>
</select>
<select id="dose">
  <option value="0">SELECT dose</option>
</select>
```